# How to go to an activty at a specific time using Broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

When I set a time,how to start an activity or do some actions like button click actions(**not toast**) at that specific time using broadcast receiver??

Comment: Did you mean how to make some action in specific time. after you receive some data from broadcast?

Comment: Actually from main activity i want to do a action(not toast) using broadcast receiver at a specific time like(3:30pm).From main activity it goes to broadcast receiver class using pending intent.In broadcast receiver class all i can do is toast action.i cant use a button inside that class...since it is not an activity

Comment: You should use AlarmManager + Service. Look at my new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need AlarmManager + Service to do that.
you can look it here

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

and in Service class (in the link) that display Toast, 
just make some new intent and startActivity(intent) there
PS. before start. It's important that you must add this line also

```
youintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

like this

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

private Intent alarmIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);
    alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    //Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    //      .show();

    startActivity(alarmIntent);
}

// another implement method......
}
```

Comment: Yes..Thnx for the answer....It starts a new activity..but i wanted some action inside that activity at a specific time...

Answer (score 0):

You might need Handler;

```
Intent intent;
Handler handler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    intent = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class);
    handler = new Handler();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_streaming_client_example);


}
```

and to make it run at specific time use handler.postAtTime

```
handler.postAtTime(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
        MotherActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
}, millisecond_toStartfromUpTime);
```

if you want to post after some seconds, use handler.postDelayed

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
        MotherActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
}, millisecond_delayhere);
```